# Explain the switch case program?

Tags: java

```
class SwitchDemo
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        String name="aeiouuu";
        int vo=0,co=0;
        char c[]=name.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++)
        {
            switch(c[i])
            {
                case 'a':case 'e':case 'i':case 'o':case 'u':
                vo++;

                default :
                co++;
                System.out.println("co");
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Number of vowels are : "+vo);
        System.out.println("Number of consonants are : "+co);
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
Number of vowels are : 7
Number of consonants are : 7
```

but I can't understand this program because all are vowels how it is possible?

Comment: Because the first part of the `switch` doesn't have a `break`.

Comment: You need to add the break

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Add break after vo++;

Comment: Incidentally, this is why `switch` statements can be a bad idea and why you might be better served with an `if(c[i] == 'a' || c[i] == 'e' || c[i] == 'i' || c[i] == 'o' || c[i] == 'u'){vo++;}else{co++;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might make a little more sense if you write it as

```
                case 'a':
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'o':
                case 'u':
                    vo++;

                default :
                    co++;
                    System.out.println("co");
                    break;
```

And then consider that evaluating the `switch` statement is to find the first matching `case` and then to keep running until either the end of the block or a break statement.

So what is happening in your code is that you increment `vo`, and then continue to evaluate code and increment `co`. To prevent it from doing so, you should probably have it hit a `break` statement first.  Possibly something like

```
                case 'a':
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'o':
                case 'u':
                    vo++;
                    break;

                default :
                    co++;
                    System.out.println("co");
                    break;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing break statement:

```
case 'a':case 'e':case 'i':case 'o':case 'u':
   vo++;
   break;//this is what you are missing
   default :
```

If you don't provide break, your default case also gets executed and hence it increments co variable as well.